# Can ISP limit my downstream to a specific website?

Tags: bandwidth, isp

i do not mean access restrictions/censorship and bans based on IP address or domain names. For ex. i am connected to the Internet from a PC on a  private network. i have access to X and Y websites. What i access is streaming video on both sites. However, the video on one of them gets stuck at each 4 seconds. On the other website, there is no problem, its really smooth. If i deep in more specific, there is a live fashion show on one of the websites. Lets say the other is youtube video (saved one). The fashion show doesn't load as quick as youtube video and so slow compared to it. Actually, the specific website may not have adequate downstream for viewers that time or there is a load on that server due to so many users connected atthe same time.

But, as other factor, Can ISP limit my downstream to that live fashion show? and how?

Comment: If an ISP can block your access to a certain website, they can limit the bandwidth you receive when you visit the same website, doesn't mean that actually is going to happen ( if you think it is then you would be mistaken ).

Answer (score 1):

There are many factors that could be causing you to have a slow connection. Your ISP can throttle your connection to other sites. This is seen as unfair by many and has sparked many debates on net neturality. https://www.eff.org/issues/net-neutrality

But it might not be your ISP's fault that your connection is slow. It might be that the video hosting site you are trying to watch your fashion show on is not big enough to support the amount of users its has. If too many people are trying to watch videos on it at once then the service will slow down. You don't see this with youtube because youtube have hundreds of servers the distribute its content.

Or, it might be that the website you are trying to watch the slow video on has been badly designed and just does not work properly even if your connection is very good.

The problem with troubleshooting networking issues with the internet is trying to find exactly where the problem is.

Comment: well, how about if this is really done by the government controlled ISP to all people in that country 'deliberately'? (and those sites offered much better bandwidth before?)

Comment: Well if the government ISP IS throttling your bandwidth there isn't much that you can do about it. You could try a proxy or a VPN but it wont be as fast as connecting directly to the site but it could be faster than when the website is throttled

Answer (score 0):

This could certainly be the case, even inadvertently. You may have only a single connection to your ISP, but your ISP almost certainly has multiple incoming connections to other ISPs and data centres. If one of their incoming connections is congested, only content coming in over that connection will suffer.